# Couchbase Lite client with mysql backend

Tags: synchronization, couchdb

I have an android application that it must has offline capabality.I want to use CouchDB Lite in android client and i have a web service for mysql server that return json or xml document .i want to know is there any way to sync couch db lite with mysql backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're interested in using Couchbase Lite (I don't think there's a CouchDB Lite) on android.

To sync with any CouchDB like database (Couchbase/PouchDB) a database needs to implement the [CouchDB replication protocol](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/replication/protocol.html). As MySQL doesn't do that natively, it can't directly sync with Couchbase Lite.

What you can do, and this is by no means a trivial exercise, is write an app that sits between Couchbase Lite and MySQL. This app can implement the replication protocol and map Couchbase Lite documents to tables/records in MySQL.

Comment: How I implement it in android app ?